# How to use num_elements from TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I just want the number of elements in my tensor, regardless of shape.

I see in the documentation [`num_elements`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape#num_elements) serves my purpose. However, if I try to use it as `myTensor.num_elements()`, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'num_elements'

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method belongs to `TensorShape` instead of `Tensor`. You can get the number of elements like this

```py
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.random.uniform((1,16,23))
a.shape.num_elements()
# 368
```

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks man. Time to replace my `sum(myTensor.get_shape().as_list())`